# Firebase: 404 Error to access csv files at directory data inassets

Tags: angular, firebase, assets, firebase-hosting

I am using **Firebase** to host my site. I have this directory structure:

```
[Project]
|
-->dist
  |
  -->assets
     |
     -->data.csv
```

Chrome console says 404 error in the console. How can I access csv files in **Firebase**?

my **firebaserc.jso**n is:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "mycv-e3c38"
  }
}
```

and **firebase.json**:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using to get the data **Papaparser** in the service like

```
...
private _Papa: any = null;
...
constructor(private http: Http, private papa: PapaParseService) {
    this._Papa = papa;
}

...
this._Papa.parse("assets/data.csv", {
    worker: false,
    download: true,
    delimiter: ":",
    complete: function (result) {                   
        ...
    }
});
...
```

I found this code to set permissions, where do I have to set it?

```
match /public/{imageId} {
  allow read: if imageId.matches(".*\\.csv");
  allow write: if imageId.matches(".*\\.csv");
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe exactly how you are trying to access `data.csv` from your deployed web site.

Comment: it is edited. so sorry. now It is right. I don't know if in firebase I need to set any kind of permissions in that directory

Comment: do you need more information?

Comment: You still haven't explained how you are trying to access the file that's giving you a 404.

Comment: true, now added, sorry again

Comment: I don't see how your code knows what hostname to use for the HTTP request.  Is it correct?

Comment: locally sets **http://localhost:4200/assets/data.csv** and it is working in local

Comment: So, you're not going to be able to use localhost for deployed assets.

Comment: I think it is mayve something of permissions I add a code in the question but I don't know where I have to write it in firebase